# Como usar a validação do form no model (MVC)?

Tags: php, mvc

Preciso usar MVC no sistema e quero saber se as validações la no cadastro.php com $_SESSION['token'] deve ficar em UserModel. Quem puder ajudar...
Nao manjo muito

*cadastro.php*

```
<?php
    $sessao = 'cadastro';
    session_name($sessao);
    session_start();
    // Segurança contra CSRF (formularios de login,etc)
    $_SESSION['token'] = (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) ? hash('sha512', rand(100, 1000)) : $_SESSION['token'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="br">
<head>
<title>Cadastro</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link href="www/cliente/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="www/cliente/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="www/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="www/cliente/css/pages/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="www/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="www/cliente/css/jquery-confirm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="www/js/jquery-confirm.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function verificaNumero(e){
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)){
        return false;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cpf").keypress(verificaNumero);
});
function FormataCpf(evt){
    vr = (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') ?evt.target.value : evt.srcElement.value;
        if(vr.length == 3) vr = vr+".";
        if(vr.length == 7) vr = vr+".";
        if(vr.length == 11) vr = vr+"-";
    return vr;
}
</script>
<style>
h2 {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body id="cadastroClientes">
<div class="main-inner">
<div class="container">
<?php
// USAR VALIDAÇÕES NO UserModel
if(isset($_POST['cadastro']) && $_POST['cadastro'] != $_SESSION['token']){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          $.alert({
          theme: 'black',
          title: 'Detectado uso de token inválido, a página será atualizada!',
          content: '',
          icon: '',
          confirmButton: 'OK',
          confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
          animation: 'scale',
          animationClose: 'top',
          opacity: 0.5,
          confirm: function () {
            location.href='index.php';
          }
          });
          </script>";
}
if(isset($_POST['cadastro']) && $_POST['cadastro'] == $_SESSION['token']){
    $nome = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome'));
    $cpf = html_entity_decode(strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf')), ENT_QUOTES);
    $cpf2 = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $cpf);
    $login = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login'));
    $senhaAtual = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senhaAtual'));
    $atual = sha1(md5($senhaAtual));

    $senha = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha'));
    $pass = sha1(md5($senha));

    $conta_caracteres_nome = strlen($nome);
    $conta_caracteres_login = strlen($login);
    $conta_caracteres_senha = strlen($atual);

    $val->set($cpf2, 'CPF')->isCpf();

    $verificarUsuarioLogin = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT id_cliente FROM `loja_clientes` WHERE login = ?");
    $verificarUsuarioLogin->execute(array($login));

    $verificarUsuarioCPF = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT id_cliente FROM `loja_clientes` WHERE cpf = ?");
    $verificarUsuarioCPF->execute(array($cpf2));   

    if(!$val->validar()){
        $erros = $val->getErro();
        echo '<div class="erros">'.$erros[0].'</div>';
    }elseif(empty($_POST["nome"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["cpf"]) || empty($_POST["login"]) || empty($_POST["senhaAtual"])){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              $.alert({
              theme: 'black',
              title: 'Preencha todos os campos!',
              content: '',
              icon: '',
              confirmButton: 'OK',
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
              animation: 'scale',
              animationClose: 'top',
              opacity: 0.5,
              });
              </script>";
    }elseif(empty($_POST["senha"])){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              $.alert({
              theme: 'black',
              title: 'Repita a senha!',
              content: '',
              icon: '',
              confirmButton: 'OK',
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
              animation: 'scale',
              animationClose: 'top',
              opacity: 0.5,
              });
              </script>";
    }elseif(!is_numeric($cpf2)){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              $.alert({
              theme: 'black',
              title: 'O campo CPF deve conter apenas números!',
              content: '',
              icon: '',
              confirmButton: 'OK',
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
              animation: 'scale',
              animationClose: 'top',
              opacity: 0.5,
              });
              </script>";
    }elseif($verificarUsuarioLogin->rowCount() > 0){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              $.alert({
              theme: 'black',
              title: 'Já existe um cliente com este nome de usuário!',
              content: '',
              icon: '',
              confirmButton: 'OK',
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
              animation: 'scale',
              animationClose: 'top',
              opacity: 0.5,
              });
              </script>";
    }elseif($verificarUsuarioCPF->rowCount() > 0){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              $.alert({
              theme: 'black',
              title: 'Já existe um cliente com este CPF!',
              content: '',
              icon: '',
              confirmButton: 'OK',
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
              animation: 'scale',
              animationClose: 'top',
              opacity: 0.5,
              });
              </script>";
    }elseif($conta_caracteres_nome < 10){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              $.alert({
              theme: 'black',
              title: 'Informe o seu nome completo!',
              content: '',
              icon: '',
              confirmButton: 'OK',
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
              animation: 'scale',
              animationClose: 'top',
              opacity: 0.5,
              });
              </script>";
    }elseif($conta_caracteres_login < 5){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              $.alert({
              theme: 'black',
              title: 'O nome de usuário informado é muito curto!',
              content: '',
              icon: '',
              confirmButton: 'OK',
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
              animation: 'scale',
              animationClose: 'top',
              opacity: 0.5,
              });
              </script>";
    }elseif($conta_caracteres_senha < 8){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              $.alert({
              theme: 'black',
              title: 'A senha deve conter no mínimo 8 caracteres. Utilize letras, números e símbolos!',
              content: '',
              icon: '',
              confirmButton: 'OK',
              confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
              animation: 'scale',
              animationClose: 'top',
              opacity: 0.5,
              });
              </script>";
    }else{
        if($atual == $pass){
            $dados3 = array($nome, $cpf2, $login, $pass);
            if($site->cadastrarCliente($dados3)){
                $_SESSION['token'] = hash('sha512', rand(100, 1000));
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                          $.alert({
                          theme: 'black',
                          title: 'Cadastrado com sucesso!',
                          icon: '',
                          confirmButton: 'OK',
                          confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
                          animation: 'scale',
                          animationClose: 'top',
                          opacity: 0.5,
                          confirm: function (){
                            location.href='index.php';
                          }
                          });
                          </script>";
                    die();
            }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="padding:8px 14px 8px 14px; border-radius:0px;">
                      <strong><h3>Erro ao cadastrar!</h3></strong>
                      </div>';
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                  $.alert({
                  theme: 'black',
                  title: 'Informe a mesma senha nos campos: Senha e Repita a senha!',
                  content: '',
                  icon: '',
                  confirmButton: 'OK',
                  confirmButtonClass: 'btn-primary',
                  animation: 'scale',
                  animationClose: 'top',
                  opacity: 0.5,
                  });
                  </script>";
        }  
    }
}
```

*UserModel.php*

```
<?php
    namespace Application\Models;
    use Application\Models\Model;

    class UserModel extends Model
    {
        public static function cadastrar(array $dados)
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `loja_clientes` (nome, cpf, email, login, senha) VALUES (:nome, :cpf, :email, :login, :senha)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
            $stmt->bindParam(':cpf', $cpf);
            $stmt->bindParam(':login', $login);
            $stmt->bindParam(':senha', $senha);

            if ($stmt->execute())
            {
                return true;
            } else {
                echo "Erro ao cadastrar";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No meu ponto de vista, você poderia pegar essa parte da validação e criar um ViewModel, deixando a seu cargo essa responsabilidade e mais o que ocorrer com esses dados antes de serem usados.

Deixe o Model responsável somente pelo domínio.

View<->ViewModel <-Controller-> Model(Domain).

Sei que esta utilizando PHP como linguagem, mas estude o que o [Eduardo Pires](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-view-model-pattern-quando-e-como-utilizar/) esta explicando sobre o Padrão ViewModel, servira para aplicar em qualquer linguagem, afinal o importante são os conceitos.

Grato.